# Volume control: is there a really silent setting?

Tags: settings, volume-control, volume

I like to listen to the radio in the background with earbuds. So I turn the volume down all the way, but in the lowest setting the volume is still about two to three times as loud is I want it to be.

Is there a way to tune the master-volume (or the volume of one app) to something less still than 1/10 without going totally silent?

Comment: Which device? Which version of Android?

Comment: [FP1](http://www.fairphone.com/fairphone/) with 4.2.2